# Reverse animation in datatrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this animation:

```
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation From="15" To="85" Duration="00:00:0.7" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
              <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                 <BounceEase Bounces="2" EasingMode="EaseOut" Bounciness="5" />
              </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
          </Storyboard>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
 </DataTrigger>
```

Which will trigger when my `StackPanel` is visible. My problem is to create the reverse animation, when to stackpanel changes it's visibility to Collapsed. I've tried with the `ExitActions` inside the `DataTrigger` I've also tried by creating a new `DataTrigger` which sets the binding to `Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=IsVisible}" Value="False"`

But none of these attemps gave me the correct reverse animation. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that the problem is that the stack panel is collapsed before the animation can execute (the fact that it is collapsed triggers the subsequent animation), then you can't see it

Comment: What you should do is to trigger the Visibility change via animation. So you can execute the bounce and fade out then set the Visibility to Collapsed from the same storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this code can suit your need (an external event triggers the animation) ?

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="conv"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CheckBox x:Name="chk" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="false"></CheckBox>


    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Height="0">
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chk,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <Storyboard x:Name="mySowStoryboard">
                                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="85" Duration="00:00:0.7" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <BounceEase Bounces="2" EasingMode="EaseOut" Bounciness="5" />
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <Storyboard x:Name="myhideStoryboard">
                                        <DoubleAnimation From="85" To="0" Duration="00:00:0.7" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <BounceEase Bounces="2" EasingMode="EaseOut" Bounciness="5" />
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>

            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
        <Border Background="Black" BorderBrush="DeepPink" BorderThickness="2">
            <TextBlock Margin="20" Text="I'm here" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: it doesnt seems to work, the behaviour is the same as in my question. The animation should be triggered by a boolean value, or as you have in your example a checkbox IsChecked property.

Comment: I slightly updated my code snippet but this works perfectly : the stack panel is not visible at the beginning (height=0) and shows with the animation when triggered by the external value (here the checkbox but can be anything else, for example a property in your viewmodel). Unchecking the checkbox triggers the exit action and the stackpanel looks like its collapsing.
But you have to remove all visibility triggers : bind the data trigger directly to your boolean triggers rather than using the visibility

Comment: I'll try this in a couple of minutes, and will provid feedback. Thanks

Comment: It works when pasting it into Kaxaml application. So I would assume that there is something else in my code. I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Can you paste more of your code ? for example the class that should trigger the animation ?

Comment: I've fixed it now, It was as you mentioned, a visibility trigger. Thanks for you effort!